# Bootstrap Modal shown.bs.modal event executing multiple times

Tags: jquery

This is the code:

```
$("#button").click(function(event){
     $('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) { 
         $("#target").effect( "shake");
       });
});
```

The problem:

When the modal shows for the first time, the `#target` is shaking once and it works fine. But when I click the button again, the `#target` is shaking twice, and click again target is shaking 3x, and then 4x.

Everytime I click the button, the shaking increments until I refresh the browser.

This is because the execution of event shown.bs.modal increments everytime the button was click.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incremental shaking is happening because every time the button is clicked, it creates a new event handler for the `shown.bs.modal` event.

If you were to track the event handlers for this event it would look like this:

- Before the button is clicked: 0 event handlers
- Button clicked once: 1 event handlers
- Button clicked twice: 2 event handlers
- ...

To avoid this, you could clear the `show.bs.modal` event handler after shaking  with JQuery's [off](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_off.asp) function so the code looks like this:

```
$("#button").click(function(event){
     $('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) { 
         $("#target").effect( "shake");
         // 'this' is the '#modal' element
         this.off('shown.bs.modal');
     });
});
```

Comment: Exact answer! **this.off('shown.bs.modal')** solved the problem. Thanks @Ryan Rossiter.

Comment: @Ryan.Do you have any suggestion how to improve my question? I dont know how to explain it clearly.Thanks!